# When a value is added via Map.put(K, V), must the same instance be returned via Map.get(K)?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, semantics

Suppose you have this code:

```
Map<Foo, Bar> map = new HashMap<Foo, Bar>();

Foo foo = new Foo();
Bar bar = new Bar();
map.put(foo, bar);

Bar barReturned = map.get(foo);
```

Does Java require that `barReturned == bar`? That is, does Java *require* that `barReturned` be *the same instance* as `bar`? If not, what semantics are expected?

The [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) suggests that `barReturned == bar` must be true, but I'm not 100% sure:

> **`V get(Object key)`**
>
> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or `null` if this map contains no mapping for the key.
>
> More formally, if this map contains a mapping from a key `k` to a value `v` such that `(key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))`, then this method returns `v`; otherwise it returns `null`. (There can be at most one such mapping.)
>
> If this map permits `null` values, then a return value of null does not *necessarily* indicate that the map contains no mapping for the key; it's also possible that the map explicitly maps the key to `null`. The containsKey operation may be used to distinguish these two cases.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `key` - the key whose associated value is to be returned
>
> **Returns:**
>
> ***THE VALUE TO WHICH THE SPECIFIED KEY IS MAPPED***, or `null` if this map contains no mapping for the key

(Emphasis mine)

**Edit:** I understand that the implementations of `Map` that come bundled with the standard library adhere to the `barReturned == bar` semantics. What I want to know is whether or not this behavior is **required** as per the documentation. For example, must I also adhere to these semantics if I write my own class that implements `Map`?

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking whether you can break that relation, i think the answer is "yes".  for instance, if you were implementing a Map which acted like a persistent cache, a specific value may be written to disk if not used in a while, then reloaded later.  you will not have reference equality in that situation, but that's okay.  obviously, you would want to document any deviations from standard behavior, but i don't think this is out of the realm of a reasonable usage of a Map.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it will be **the same** instance. Otherwise `Map` would be useless.

Though, the only exception to this is multi-threaded application, where other thread can put arbitrary value to the same key in between your calls to `put` and `get`.

---

**Edit** As Adam pointed out in comments, he have special case where his implementation of Map can recreate incoming objects and use their copies instead. Copies in the sense `original.equals(copy)` is true and `original == copy` is false. In this case I think Map can store copy instead of original.

Comment: Are you sure? Would `Map` be rendered useless if `get(K)` returned an object such that `barReturned.equals(bar) && barReturned != bar`? Just curious.

Comment: No, it wouldn't! One application of such a map is hash-consing, which is a discipline to ensure that you have only one object in place of many objects which are equivalent.

Comment: The only way to achieve such behavior I can think of is via reflection API -- you could try to assemble instances of the same type with same state. Though, I have doubts if reflection will allow to copy state contained in `private` fields.

Comment: @Victor: The `Map` implementation I am considering is a specialized class whose keys and values are of a specific class (that is, it's not a `Map` that can work with just any `K` and `V`). This map implementation knows how to create equivalent instances of its keys and values.

Comment: @Victor Sorokin: in Java, reflection can access and modify private fields, except if there is a SecurityManager that is being enforced

Comment: @Adam Paynter If you have special case where you can reproduce objects in Map, then it shall be possible to discard incoming object and store it's copy in Map. Seems like kind of object pooling to me. I will adjust my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

If you interpret the term **value** used in the javadocs as the **reference** to the object in the map it would imply that you always need to return the same reference as you put in the map and you would have == equality. Then it becomes more of a question of the definition of the term value used in the docs.

Comment: Good points. Oh, terminology! I wish the authors had provided code samples in the Javadoc explicitly stating the required semantics.

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc does not sate (or limit) it clearly that values that you put in the map are physically equal to those that have been put into it.
So I'd dare to say that there is no 100% guarantee, that it must be so.
You probably could assume that:

```
Map<Foo,Bar> map = new HashMap<Foo,Bar>();
Foo foo = new Foo();
Bar bar = new Bar();
map.put(foo, bar);

System.out.println( bar.equals( map.get(foo) ) ); // ==> Should be guaranteed
System.out.println( bar == map.get(foo) );        // ==> no guarantee
```

You could in theory create a clustered Map implementation that is shared and synchronized on different JVMs, in this case it would be impossible (or at least really difficult) to obtain the same physical instance.

My opinion is that in your implementation you should guarantee that `bar.equals( map.get(foo) )` but not necessarly `bar == map.get(foo)`.
However as long as you clearly document and state that both of the above is not guaranteed, you can do what you want with your Map implementation. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're implementing your own version of Map, yes you don't need to return the same object instance. There is nothing in the doc and language that requires your implementation to return the same object instance.

Your code might break if and only if there is some library or other parts of your code that made the (unwarranted, though generally reasonable) assumption that the return value will be the same object instance. In this case, well, just don't pass your implementation of Map to that code.

```
Patient: Doctor, it hurts when I do this
Doctor: Well, don't do that
```

Answer (score 1):

Note it says the "value" to which the key is mapped, not the "reference" or "instance."  When you hear "value", it suggests Object.equals() semantics.  You have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Even if the value is mutable? Suppose I have a `Map<String, Collection<String>>` (whose values are *mutable* collections). Would `Map` require that the `Collection<String>` returned by `get()` *always* be `equal` to the `Collection<String>` I originally inserted (even if the original collection has changed)?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo{

}
class Bar{

}
public class MapDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Foo,Bar> map = new HashMap<Foo,Bar>();
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        map.put(foo, bar);
        System.out.println(bar == map.get(foo));
    }
}
```

Returns **true**

`HashMap` implements `Map` but there is nothing written such.

```
  /**
  137        * Returns the value of the mapping with the specified key.
  138        * 
  139        * @param key
  140        *            the key.
  141        * @return the value of the mapping with the specified key, or {@code null}
  142        *         if no mapping for the specified key is found.
  143        */
```

But almost each implementation does this, I mean it maintains the same Object

Comment: I know that, but does Java *require* those semantics? For example, if I implement my own class that implements `Map`, must I also adhere to those semantics?

Comment: This just confirms the suggestion with the current version of the JVM, with a user defined class. It does not prove whether this behaviour is required by the standard.

Comment: @Adam Paynter: Well, it says so in the interface description. But unless you will export that function for public use, you could do as you wish. The language itself will not care what you do as long as the syntax is right.

Comment: @Tobias I don't see any such specification with `java.util.Map`

Comment: @Jigar True, it could be a copy, I must have been thinking too fast on this one.